# JavaScript click event after confirmation dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a button that has two click handlers on it:

1. Show a native JavaScript confirmation dialog to the user to confirm the action.
2. Set some attributes on a separate form element, and submit that form.

They’re jQuery-based and look like this:

```js
$('[data-confirm]').on('click', function (e) {
  if (! confirm($(this).data('confirm')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});

$('.js-remove-item').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log('clicked');

  var $form = $('#remove-item-form');

  $form.attr('action', $(this).data('url'));
  $form.submit();
});
```

The button HTML looks like this:

```html
<button type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary js-remove-item"
        data-confirm="Are you sure you want to remove this item?">
```

However, the console logs “clicked” as the confirmation dialog is displayed. I only want that event listener fired if the user *confirms* the action.

How would I go about this?

Comment: why is the confirm and the code in two different click handlers? Problem with two clicks is the fact that the confirm one needs to be registered before the submit one.

Comment: Your code is working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6hs9nd50/) - as long as the `[data-confirm]` click handler is defined before the `.js-remove-item` click handler.

Comment: idk why your code doesn't work, but i would add a flag on the element in the confirm: `if(confirm) $(this).data("confirmed", true)` and then check for it in the other handler

Comment: @epascarello Because they’re separate components. The first one is a generic component to add confirmation dialogs to _any_ links/buttons, not just this particular one. The second listener is one I want to fire for this _particular_ button.

Comment: And the problem you have is event order. The confirmation is added after the click so it is not possible to stop the action. If you change the confirmation to use mousedown, you have a shot. Other option is to have your code listen for onsubmit of the form instead of a click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a solution for this.

For the “remove item” logic, instead of attaching the class to the button itself I’ve added it to a parent element. Using bubbling, it means any listeners on the button itself are triggered (the confirmation dialog). If that event propagates, it will do so to its parent, which has the “remove item” class name and logic bound.